# Removing an empty line with .replaceAll and regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Pardon if this was answered already. I have hunted for two days for an answer just and finally got this far. Here is the problem to solve:

Write a method called stripComments that accepts a Scanner representing an input file containing a Java program as its parameter, reads that file, and then prints the file's text with all comments removed. A comment is any text on a line from // to the end of the line, and any text between /* and */ characters. For example, consider the following text:

```
import java.util.*;

/* My program
by Suzy Student */
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!"); // a println
    }

    public static /* Hello there */ void foo() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!"); // comment here
    } /* */
}
```

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void stripComments(Scanner scan) {
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String str1 = scan.nextLine();
        String str2 = str1.replaceAll("(/(\\*).*?(\\*)/)|(//.*?$)|(/(\\*).*?$)|([a-zA-Z\\s0-9]*?\\*(/))", "");
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
import java.util.*;


    public class Program {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, world!"); 
        }

        public static  void foo() {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
        } 
    }
```

While most of it correct, I don't know how to get rid of the extra line above "public class Program {." How do I get rid of the line and is there a better way to write the regex expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But `/* ... */` command can be multi line also. Does your regex cover them?

Comment: Why don't you want to simply use apache commons `StringUtils.isBlank(str2)` or `isEmpty(String str)` and don't print the line if it is blank/empty. You can also check if `str1` isNotBlank if you want to leave empty lines that were without comments.

Comment: Why are you using so many capturing groups? You could rewrite this entire regex pattern without any `(` or `)` and it would serve exactly the same function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the text being worked on. I have edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a second replace command

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n\\s*\n", "\n");
```

This requires that you pass in the entire file though, it wouldn't work line by line.

If you want to continue going line by line, you should just do

```
if(str2.matches("\\s*"))
    continue;
```

P.S. The last grouping of parenthesis around your regex is unnecessary if you don't have a quantifier. And your multiline comment won't work with 3+ lines, such as:

```
/*
 * This is
 * a multiline
 * Comment
 */
```

Since you are passing it in line by line.